# Which file does apt update actually work on?

Tags: apt

My internet connection went off while I was running `apt update`, so to restore my system to initial state I was wondering which file `apt update` actually works on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It updates a number of files under `/var/lib/apt`. There’s no need to restore any state, if you run it again it will figure things out on its own.